# PHP, Javascript JSON, XSS Protection

Tags: php, javascript, json, xss

I am considered about XSS vulnerability!

I have web site, where All data b/w web server and client is transferred via XHR - JSON and browser javascript doing the rest to display the site.

When client submit data, here is my code BEFORE data to be recorded in DB (PHP):

```
$string = trim($_POST['user_input']);
$string = strip_tags($string);
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```

When the server getting data form database PHP code is following:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars($db_value);
```

and then

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
print json_encode($string);
```

Is this enough to protect me against XSS?

Comment: If you're sending a normal XMLHttpRequest you're not prone to XSS unless you actually place the response content you loaded from the AJAX anywhere. Where/how do you present it to the user?

Comment: Just to mention, you can put all of those functions in one line of code. $string = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['string'])));

Comment: @Brad thanks mate, i know but in the question i've wrote them separated just to be easier for read.

Comment: JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT) options for escaping HTML special chars and header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff") for IE are also needed.

Comment: You mean to say that you are *concerned* about XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, the other answer here is not correct. Using application/json for your content-type will fix some problems, but many clients tend to extract data from a JSON object and display it on a page. This leads to a classic attack.

The ONLY reliable method to stop XSS (and I say reliable because it's not fool-proof) is to sanitize data on the inbound stream (rejecting requests entirely is probably a better call) and encoding ALL output that has the potential to be displayed (ie: anything the user could have modified).

Also, don't accept the idea that methods not designed for security are inherently secure (json_encode is not meant for XSS security, and should not be used as such). Any suggestion that normal security practices are not necessary because of X should be viewed with skepticism if not outright disregarded.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends.  If the contents of `$string` post json_encode contain HTML entities and are displayed as html on a page then you would be vulnerable to XSS.  If that's not the case (and it's not since you're using `application/json` anyway) then not only is there no need to use `htmlspecialchars`, it's probably undesirable because it alters the raw data you are trying to transfer via JSON.

I won't say that you are completely invulnerable to XSS because it is limited only by the imagination of evil people, but I would say that `header('Content-Type: application/json;')` provides sufficient protection in this instance.

On an unrelated note, stop using [`ext/mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Comment: okay, so i'll give you an example, if i dont htmlspecialchars() before sending JSON to client, in this case i am completely vulnerable. <div id="container" data-string="+AJAX_RESULT.STRING+"></div>

Comment: @OlegPopov not necessarily; it depends on how it is going to be consumed by the client.  Is it displayed as HTML?  Probably not

Comment: Yep, actually is displayed as normal HTML. if STRING is " onmouseover="alert('WTF!')" - it's alerting. Thats why i am using  htmlspecialchars($string).